# Error retrieving SNMP data by getting SNMP query

Tags: c#, snmp

I have written a simple tool, to get manufacturer and model with the SharpSnmpLib.

The problem is: when I run the tool, the console window still shows:

> Error retrieving SNMP data: Request timed out after 6000-ms

The IP is correct, SNMPv1/v2 reading is active.

Here is the code, written in C# running on .NET 4.8.

My testprinter is a HP OfficeJet 8010.

Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib;
using Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // SNMP-Informationen for Printer
        string targetIpAddress = "192.168.31.10";
        string communityString = ""; // Not necessary

        // OID for Printer manufacturer and model
        string manufacturerOid = "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"; // SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0
        string modelOid = "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"; // SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0

        try
        {
            // SNMP query for Printer manufacturer and model
            var result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V2, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(targetIpAddress), 161), new OctetString(communityString), new List<Variable> { new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(manufacturerOid)), new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(modelOid)) }, 120000);

            // Result anzeigen
            if (result != null && result.Count == 2)
            {
                var manufacturerData = result[0].Data.ToString();
                var modelData = result[1].Data.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine($"Printer Manufacturer: {manufacturerData}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Printer Model: {modelData}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SNMP query failed.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error retrieving SNMP data: {ex.Message}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using Port 161 which is SNMP.  You can use a sniffer (wireshark or fiddler) to see if connection completes.  From your code, it looks like connection is never completing.  Your IP could be wrong, there may not be a route to the IP, or the IP may be rejecting the data in the message.  The sniffer would indicate if the connection completes.  You may want to read following : https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/7244-snmp-trap.html